# Laravel 5 how can add dynamic number of row on list view

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Current I use LengthAwarePaginator for paging on laravel.
I have a problem with number of row on list view.
I have total 8 record, and paging with 3 items per page => I have 3 page.
I want first page, column number is: 1, 2, 3.
and second page, column number is: 4, 5, 6
and next page, column number is: 7, 8, ...

And current I foreach array and get by key => it always begin from 1 for every page.

[image]
[image]

I spend many time for this problem. Please help me resolved it. many thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pagination object is called `$results`, I think you can use this:

```
($results->currentPage()-1) * $results->perPage() + $key
```

So, on page 1 it would be `(1-1)*3+1=1` for the first record.

On page 2 it would be `(2-1)*3+1=4` for the first record.